# Converting datetime column value to server datetime value

Tags: 2007, xslt, date-time

I am trying to build a calendar with date time columns. My SP 2007 server is in US and I am trying to use this site in India. My server returns the EventDate column value in India format. I want to convert it in US date.

For example:

---

```
My Event Date I set is: 5/29/2012 3:00 PM
I want to convert it in: 5/29/2012 2:30 AM (US Time)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert a datetime to an other timezone in c# you can use this:

```
TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo; 

DateTime dateTime ; 

//Set the time zone information to US Mountain Standard Time 

timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("US Mountain Standard Time"); 

//Get date and time in US Mountain Standard Time 

dateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now, timeZoneInfo);

//Print out the date and time

Console.WriteLine(dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss"));
```

A List of TimeZones and further documentation you can find [here](http://www.xiirus.net/articles/article-_net-convert-datetime-from-one-timezone-to-another-7e44y.aspx):

And in the MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.getsystemtimezones.aspx

Conversion with XSLT: http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_adjust-datetime-to-timezone.html

Comment: I am trying to convert timezones in XSLT in SharePoint Designer.

Comment: I am getting a way I think. However i am unable to use function adjust-dateTime-to-timezone(). It gives me error:

`adjust-dateTime-to-timezone is not a valid XSLT or XPath function.`

Am I missing a xmlnamespace? An example would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @Ashish I think it is is a XPath 2.0 function, looks as if you called it from a 1.0 processor.

Comment: I changed the version of my xsl:stylesheet declaration to version="2.0". How can i check if I can process 2.0 functions as well?

Comment: @Ashish try one of these functions: saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon7.4/functions.html

Comment: as you said, i may be using 2.0 functions with 1.0 processor. How can I make sure I can still use 2.0 functions in my MOSS 2007 environment? This list are the functions I can use with 2.0 processor.

Comment: @Ashish I'm sorry, I do not know how to check it. In my view it would be best practise to put it into a new seperate question.